# How do I remove this shower handle so I can adjust the water temp?

Tags: plumbing, delta

I am trying to adjust water temp, but I have to get the handle off first. Pix included.

I removed the hex screw; tried to pull the handle off; didn't work.  Do I just need to pull harder or am I supposed to turn it? counter clockwise is the only direction it will go, which turns on the water.

Pix:

1-handle+
[image: handle]

2-Delta showing Delta SA below the handle on the 'backplate'
[image: Delta]

3-Pat. #3674048 - verified Delta's
[image: Pat#]
4-faucet+ says just SA on underside near a set screw; thing to close the drain says PRICE PFISTER.

[image: faucet]

I found a pic with the same handle 'Delta Faucet T13290' at Amazon; the rest is different from mine.
[https://www.amazon.com/Faucet-T13290-Classic-Monitor-Shower/dp/B001AECGHA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001AECGHA)

Comment: Chances are the handle is corroded in place a bit. A tap with a soft, heavy object might knock it loose, as might some penetrating oil.

Comment: Thank you; do you think WD40 would work.  All the websites I saw said after I removed the screw it should just pull out.

Comment: WD-40 can work. Let it soak for a while.

Comment: You can also try some CLR to dissolve any lime that might be build up.

Comment: Good idea; I hadn't thot of that

Comment: Oops; no CLR and I don't want to buy anything, but what about vinegar?  I have that.  The finish doesn't appear very 'sturdy' tho and I cannot damage anything...so hoping for more ideas.

Comment: for isherwood...do I spray the WD40 into the hole where the hex screw goes?

Comment: It will be difficult to get any liquid on to the stem.  Try wiggling it side to side, back and forth while pulling on it. Gentle taps on each side may help.

Answer (score 1):

Your tub/shower valve is definitely a Delta unit. On their older valves with the "Scald Guard" feature that set screw is the only thing that holds the handle on. As suggested in the comments, spraying with penetrating oil and tapping around the edge of the knob will usually break it loose such that you can pull it off. It is not uncommon (or unwise)for plumbers to use a *handle puller* made exactly for this task to increase the chances of saving the knob/handle:

[image]

These are $12 - $20, maybe less for a cheaply made version. Readily available at the plumbing shop, which you should become familiar with for when the knob breaks during removal...

The temp control limit stop should be a plastic widget with teeth on the underside, just behind the knob, which limits the CCW knob travel. You should be able to pull it away and rotate it CW to give the knob more CCW travel toward the hot inlet port.

Comment: Good call.   I think the give away for it being a Delta unit is the word "Delta" stamped on the trim.